# Where is the blue diagonal coming from?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import FormatStrFormatter

hour_of_day = [17, 13, 21, 21, 16, 15, 9, 10, 12, 11, 10, 1, 5, 13, 13, 18, 21, 23, 23, 14, 11, 12, 15, 17, 9, 19, 7, 20, 20, 21, 21, 19, 2, 8, 23, 8, 8, 10, 15, 11, 19, 18, 20, 22, 22, 0, 0, 10, 13, 11, 16, 18, 18, 19, 19, 19, 23, 4, 6, 11, 15, 14, 16, 21, 20, 20, 21, 21, 14, 15, 19, 20, 23, 6, 6, 14, 15, 0, 1, 1, 12, 20, 21, 21, 3, 2, 5, 6, 6, 7, 10, 10, 11, 12, 12, 9, 14, 14, 19, 15, 16, 21, 21, 22, 22, 20, 4, 6, 7, 17, 17, 18, 18, 19, 8, 14, 13, 20, 14, 0, 6, 4, 7, 13, 12, 12, 17, 19, 21, 22, 0, 0]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
counts, bins, patches = ax.hist(
    hour_of_day,bins=range(25), normed = False, color = 'g')

plt.plot(bins)
plt.show()
```

It generates the (almost) expected figure. In particular, it renders an unexplained blue(!) diagonal. What is this line? Where is it coming from? How can I disable it?

For reference, here is the result I get:

[image]

Comment: remove `plt.plot(bins)`

Comment: @behzad.nouri Why don'yt you post it as an answer writing one more line as explanation?

Comment: @pwagner because this is not a question which would help others, and it is better to be deleted by the OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, your histogram is generated by `ax.hist(
    hour_of_day,bins=range(25), normed = False, color = 'g')`.

The blue diagonal is caused by the call to `plt.plot(bins)`, which makes an x-y plot of `bins` vs your x-axis (in this case also `bins`). You can just delete this line and the unwanted blue line will go away.